# How to convert Cucumber DataTable with more than two columns to changeable list of lists?

Tags: java, testing, cucumber

I've got Cucumber DataTable like that:

Do something:

```
  | example | of            | datatable |
  | for     | stackoverflow | com       |
```

There is my java code:

```
public void someMethod(DataTable dataTable) {
    List<List<String>> rows = new ArrayList(dataTable.asLists(String.class));
    ...
```

List "rows" is changeable now, but sublists are unchanheable. How could i make them changeable without creating new fields?
I want to be able to set values to sublist elements, like that:

```
rows.get(0).set(0, "new value");
```

Now this code throws UnsupportedOperationException

Comment: The backing List<List> of the DataTable is created with the unmodifiableList() method of Collections class. One way would be to write a helper method to manually create a new list<List> by iteration. Then u cld modify it.

Comment: probably this is the only solution